# Why am I getting error class ImagePixel not found?

Tags: php, imagick

Here is a snippit of my code:

```
//$page defined above

$opening_border = new ImagickDraw();
$opening_border->setFillColor('none');
$opening_border->setstrokecolor(new ImagePixel('#000000'));
$opening_border->setstrokewidth(10);
$opening_border->setstrokeantialias(FALSE);
$opening_border->rectangle($left_px, $top_px, $width_px, $height_px);
$opening_img->drawimage($opening_border);

$page->compositeImage($opening_img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $left_px, $top_px);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ImagePixel' not found in /data/www-test/content/sites/all/modules/tf_modules/tf_fulfill/tf_fulfill_pdf_generate.php on line 333
```

This is part of my PHP info

[image: PHP info - imagick]

Comment: It's `ImagickPixel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImagickPixel is the correct name